# korn shell and environment variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, ksh

env and start.env that should run in any shell.
It actually does except for KORN where env variable setting is not behaves the way I would expect. So look at example.

*file set.env :*

```
#!/bin/bash
export MY_VAR="home" || setenv MY_VAR "home"
```

*file start.sh :*

```
#!/bin/bash
command . ./set.env || source set.env
echo "$MY_VAR"
```

i can see the print of variable.
but if try to echo it in terminal under ksh, it turned to be not defined.

```
ksh$ start.sh
home
ksh$ echo $MY_VAR

ksh$
```

I would expect to see $MY_VAR in my session... any ideas ?
//run under red hat

Comment: `setenv` is csh. Do you really need to support that completely-non-POSIX-compliant shell, or is POSIX sh (dash, ash, &c), ksh and bash sufficient?

Comment: BTW, which ksh are you actually using? If it's mksh, for instance, that's not real written-by-David-Korn ksh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `start.sh`, you're executing it as a subcommand, not sourcing it. Consequently, changes it makes to environment variables are scoped to that process and its children; once the process exits, the environment variables it sets die with it.

To portably source the script, executing it in your current shell and thus setting environment variables within that shell, run:

```
# this works on any POSIX shell, including ksh (and bastardizations such as mksh)
. start.sh
```

...or, less portably:

```
# this is a bashism
source start.sh
```

---

BTW, as a practice, `command . ./set.env` is... odd. `command` prevents execution of shell functions, but any environment where a function named `.` is defined is arguably a buggy environment. Consider `. start.sh` alone.

Comment: `source` is originally a C-shell-ism that somehow got imported into Bash.

Comment: i understood
instead of $ start.sh, should be $ . start.sh.
got  confused with the env file, which i want to "source" in start.sh to use variables from there. If I call "source set.evn" from start.sh variables are not visible even in context of start.sh.

Comment: `. set.env`, not `source set.env`, if you want to be portable to all POSIX shells.